# Why ffmpeg changes bitrate of mp3 when speeding it up?

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate

I speeded up (1.2x) an mp3 file using [these instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), but its real bitrate changed from 192 kbps (19 kHz cut-off) to 128 kbps (16 kHz cut-off). Why? Is it right? Or do I need to add any extra parameter to ffmpeg to speed up an audio without lowering a quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

128 kbps is probably the default bitrate. Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "atempo=1.2" -b:a 192k output.mp3
```

Comment: Works. It still changes a bitrate a little bit, but this is maybe by processing. But I need to know the real bitrate of an audio, which is hard to find out especially for large music collections. Is there any option, how not to change the cut-off e.g. if I don't know it?

Comment: The output will be CBR but not exactly the same rate. The bitrate is not, strictly speaking, related to the cut-off. The LAME encoder (used by ffmpeg) implements a cut-off based on the bitrate chosen. To check the frequency spectrum of an audio file, use `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=1024x1024 input-freq.png`  and view the PNG.

Comment: (better use spek to see or fakeflac to compute cut-off, but still it is an extra step and not really fast if working with large music collections) The bitrate is not strictly related to cut-off, but it slightly depends on it. This is why I asked if this change is bad or correct behavior (speeding anything up could just lower a bitrate - I don't know)

Comment: Changing audio tempo has no effect on bitrate. That is set separately. It defaults to 128k, but can always be explicitly set. The cut-off also has nothing to do with the bitrate. That is an encoder design choice.

Comment: I was told that cut-off reveals an actual bitrate (instead of the one explicitly set). If an audio file has got e.g. 192 kbps but its cut-off is around 16 kHz, then the actual bitrate is lower (128 kbps). See http://www.wikihow.com/Check-the-Real-Bitrate-of-Audio-Files. This is why I ask, because if ffmpeg lowers mp3s bitrate (during speeding it up) e.g. from 192 to 128 kbps, it probably cuts off (lowers) its cut-off (from 19 kHz to 16 kHz). And this is not correct behavior right?

Comment: Yes, assuming a smart MP3 encoder, cut-off depends on the bitrate chosen. So, a 192k MP3 with 16 khz ceiling was most likely transcoded from a 128k MP3. BUT ffmpeg doesn't decide or change bitrate due to speed change. They are independent variables. ffmpeg's default bitrate is 128k. It's not due to the speed change.

Comment: I see, I still hope there is an easier solution (e.g. another library better than ffmpeg, which uses bitrate of the input file or so) than checking it through fakeflac/spek/ffmpeg spectrum and specifying it by hand, but I must thank you so much

Comment: If you `-q 2` instead of`-b:a`, you can let the encoder decide the bitrate to use. It will analyze the input and apply the cut-off.

Comment: Works as expected, but isn't this parameter intended to a conversion between CBR and VBR?

Comment: Yes, the output is VBR. But the whole point of VBR is it allocates bits as needed. Simpler audio data gets fewer bits and complex audio gets more.

Comment: Yes, and another approach is that some older audio players can't handle with CBR correctly. Thank you